# Why is the value of the ProgramFiles variable different in cmd.exe and PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables, windows-7-x64

I am using Windows 7 Professional SP1 on a 64 bit PC. If I open up a PowerShell console and look at $env:ProgramFiles, its value is "**C:\Program Files (x86)**". However, if I open up cmd.exe and look at %ProgramFiles%, its value is "**C:\Program Files**".

Can someone explain why they're different? I would have expected them to either be the same, or for cmd.exe to be the one that thought it was living in a 32 bit environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have opened 32 bit Power Shell: *Windows Power Shell (x86)*

The value of the variable depends on the bitness of the calling process.
If you open 32 bit CMD.EXE, (`%windir%\SysWoW64\cmd.exe`) the `%ProgramFiles%` will also point to the x86 folder.